# howto: push() function in js not inserting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, push

I'm trying to use Google Maps API and i'm stuck here:

- I need an array variable(`waypts`) with certain values in a specific format.
- when ever I 'push' a value into my `waypts` variable it only returns "OBJECT" as its value.
- I need it to push the actual value set in the selected-input-text.

with jQuery and javascript(core)

**Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('document').ready(function(){
            var waypts = [];
            var temp = $('input.boom').map(function(){
                return $(this).val();
            });

            for (var i=0;i<temp.length;i++){
                waypts.push({
                    location:temp[i].value,
                    stopover:true
                });
            }
            alert(waypts);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="boom" value="boom1"><br>
    <input type="text" class="boom" value="boom2"><br>
    <input type="text" class="boom" value="boom3"><br>
    <input type="text" class="boom" value="boom4"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your code, you need to use `location:temp[i]` instead of `location:temp[i].value`. Then you will get proper values

Comment: yeah, i noticed. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to alert the attributes of the array

Try alerting waypts[0].location

To show all items of an object array do this:

```
var output="";
for (var o in waypts) {
  if (waypts.hasOwnProperty(o) {
    output += "\n"+o+":"+waypts[o].location + '-' + waypts[o].stopover;
  }
}
alert(output)
```

or for a standard array (like you had when I read your question)

```
var output="";
for (var i=0, n=waypts.length;i<n;i++) {
  output += "\n"+i+":"+waypts[i].location + '-' + waypts[i].stopover;
}
alert(output)
```

or to use jQuery

```
var output="";
$.each(waypts, function(i,item) {
  output+= i+':'+item.location+'-'+item.stopover;
});
alert(output)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I merged you answer with rory's (after yours) and i got exactly what i wanted.

Comment: You are welcome. I enhanced the answer with your kind of array

Answer (score 3):

In your current code, `waypts` will be an array of objects, each with a `location` attribute and a `stopover` attribute.

You can change your code to the following to make it cleaner;

```
var waypts = $('input.boom').map(function(){
     return {
        location: $(this).val(),
        stopover: true
     };
}).get();

// waypts is now an array of objects with `location` and `stopover` attributes.
// you can see what each value is by alerting `waypts[i].location` and `waypts[i].stopover`.
```

Answer (score 1):

Each element in your `waypts` array would be an object - you'd need to reference each value in the object individually. Try replaceing your `alert(waypts)` with this to see all the data in the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= waypts.length; i++) {
    alert(waypts[i].location);
    alert(waypts[i].stopover);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
waypts.push({
                location:temp[i].value,
                stopover:true
            });
```

you are pushing a new literal object (enclosed in `{}`) into `waypts`.

So you are adding new items to an array of these location/stopover objects.

To actually reference a `location` or `stopover` value you need to firstly index into `waypts` using `[]` (eg `waypts[0]` will point to the first such object). Secondly you need to reference the attribute you need, either `location` or `stopover`. You do this using the standard "dot notation". So for example `waypts[0].location` will give you the location value of the first item in your `waypts` array.